# How to make a method not modify a variable

Tags: java, arrays, methods, member

I realize that this is a newbie question, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around as to why my code works as it does currently.

I'm writing a program, where I have to invert arrays' values piece by piece (for example, say, `{ {1,1}, {-1,1} }` would be `{ {-1,-1}, {1,-1} }`. Since I have to do this multiple times, I made an abstract class, `public abstract class GenericMethods` and defined a static method, to make it quicker:

```
public static int[][] invert2DIntArray (int[][] inverted2DIntArray)
{
    if (inverted2DIntArray != null)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < inverted2DIntArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < inverted2DIntArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                inverted2DIntArray[i][j] *= -1;
            }
        }

        return inverted2DIntArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Including the null check, because sometimes, it'd get a null value as an input.)

Now, I have a class, that has the following member: `private int[][] possibleCaptureMoves`. I also wrote a get method, to get this member:

```
public int[][] getPossibleCaptureMoves()
{           
    if (this.getPlayerType() == PlayerType.BLACK)
    {
        return GenericMethods.invert2DIntArray(possibleCaptureMoves);
    }
    else
    {
        return possibleCaptureMoves;
    }
    return possibleCaptureMoves;
}
```

What I wanted to do here, was, that if the object's player type is BLACK, it'd return the member inversed, BUT doesn't modify the member itself. So, say the member is `{ {2,0}, {3,0} }`, and the player type is BLACK, it'd return  `{ {-2,0}, {-3,0} }`, but the `possibleCaptureMoves` would be left as it was,  `{ {2,0}, {3,0} }`. Instead, this returns `{ {-2,0}, {-3,0} }` alright, but also modifies the member to this `{ {-2,0}, {-3,0} }` value, instead of keeping it what it was.

What did I do wrong? I'm sorry, I realize this is a total rookie mistake, but I just can't see why it'd modify the original member.

Thanks in advance and have a grea

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are objects and so, whenever any method acts on them, if they are arguments, then the original values are changed.

You need to create a copy of your array.

```
int copy[][] = new int[possibleCaptureMoves.length][possibleCaptureMoves[0].length];
for(int i=0; i<copy.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<copy[i].length; j++)
    {
        copy[i][j] = possibleCaptureMoves[i][j];
    }
}
return GenericMethods.invert2DIntArray(copy);
```

Comment: Just calling `clone()` on the top-level array probably won't help enough - it won't be a *deep* clone which is what's required here.

Comment: Just a suggestion - use `System.arrayCopy` instead of manually copying the array elements.

Comment: @JonSkeet If he's using primitives, why won't `clone()` be enough?

Comment: @SaviourSelf: Because `copy` isn't an array of primitives - it's an array of `int[]` references, and that's *not* a primitive. `clone()` only performs a shallow clone, so it will create a new array which contains the same `int[]` references as the original.

Comment: @SaviourSelf Even If it had been enough, then it wouldn't have remained now. You see - Its **Jon Skeet**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `invert2DIntArray` not to modify the source array, you should create a new array inside the method, assign the required values to it and return that array.

```
public static int[][] invert2DIntArray (int[][] input)
{
    if (input != null)
    {
        int[][] inverted2DIntArray = new int[input.length][];
        for (int i=0; i < inverted2DIntArray.length; i++)
        {
            inverted2DIntArray[i] = new int[input[i].length];
            for (int j=0; j < inverted2DIntArray[i].length; j++)
            {
                inverted2DIntArray[i][j] = -1 * input[i][j];
            }
        }

        return inverted2DIntArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

BTW, your method doesn't modify the array variable. The variable is a reference to an array object, and the method can't change that reference. It can, however, change the state of the object referred by that reference.

Answer (score 0):

The method declared is static and parameters passed are also are static so you are passing static field/object which is only one instance throughout the application and when you modify from your method it would have modified values.